# Dart- Isolates are very slow when working with lists

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I want to generate a list of 300 items from a String however when this task is divided into 3 isolates,where each isolate is generating a list of 100 items it takes just as long as it would take a single isolate to generate a list of 300 items.

the fetchCoinList() method below is what is being run in the isolate and the generateList() method spawns 3 isolates.

All these isolates do work in parallel and do return their respective lists.

```
List<CoinData> fetchCoinList(ListConfig listConfig) {
  List<CoinData> coinList = [];

  for (int index = listConfig.listStart; index < listConfig.listEnd; index++) {
    if (jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['rank'] == null ||
        jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['priceUsd'] == null ||
        jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['changePercent24Hr'] ==
            null) continue;

    int rank =
        int.parse(jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['rank']);
    String name = jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['name'];
    String symbol = jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['symbol'];
    String id = jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['id'];
    double value = double.parse(
        jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['priceUsd']);
    double percentChange = double.parse(
        jsonDecode(listConfig.listData)['data'][index]['changePercent24Hr']);
    String image =
        'https://static.coincap.io/assets/icons/${symbol.toLowerCase()}@2x.png';
    print(listConfig.listEnd);

    coinList.add(CoinData(rank, id, name, symbol, value, percentChange, image));
  }
  return coinList;
}

Future<List<CoinData>> generateList(String response) async {
  print("Inside isolate");

  List<CoinData> coinList = [];
  List list = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ListConfig listConfig = ListConfig(response, i * 100, (i * 100) + 100);
    list.add(compute(fetchCoinList, listConfig));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    coinList = coinList + await list[i];
  }

  return coinList;
}
```

What could be a workaround for this problem? how would one go about generating a list of 300 or a 1000 items if required(without hanging the main thread)?

Comment: Please don't create multiple questions on the same topic. You already posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730674/flutter-main-thread-still-hangs-even-when-running-heavy-computations-on-sepera

Comment: *"how would one go about generating a list of 300 or a 1000 items if required(without hanging the main thread)?"* - so now you are calling `compute` function three times and yet the main thread hungs?

Comment: When that said. It is not clear in your example how you are calling these methods from your main-isolate.

Comment: @pskink The main thread does not hang in this case however it takes a long time for isolates to generate their respective lists...if I were to generate a list of 300 items on the main thread it would generate it in a significantly less amount of time but it will cause the ui to freeze for that amount of time.

Comment: it it normal: spawning an `Isolate` and passing your data two-ways is not a zero cost action - it takes a while

Comment: @julemand101 the generateList() function is being called in the main thread via an onPress() event which is async and uses the await keyword before generateList()

Comment: @pskink is there a better way to generate large lists(without hanging the main thread) ?because the multiple isolate approach is futile as doing so takes longer than the main thread.

Comment: @pskink I did indeed tried that approach but the results were the same

Comment: @pskink it doesnt take very long but it defeats the purpose of using multiple threads in my application as the time taken for 3 threads is the same as it would take for 1 thread. I was thinking of generating a list of 1000-2000 items but as I can observe from this approach it would take significantly longer as well.

Comment: It should also be noted that `fetchCoinList` is really not written in any efficient way at all. It is actual kinda horrible that you are calling `jsonDecode` every time you need a element from the data structure instead of saving the result of `jsonDecode`.

Comment: Similar, you should save the result of `jsonObject['data'][index]` if you are going to use the elements from this element multiple times like you are doing.

Comment: @julemand so I should convert the result of jsondecode into a list or iterable and use that to generate my objects?

Comment: @HamzaBaig Give me a few minutes to write an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241141/discussion-between-julemand101-and-hamza-baig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue are probably the kinda horrible way you are handling JSON parsing in `fetchCoinList` where you are running `jsonDecode()` for every field you want to extract from your JSON string.

You should instead cache the result from `jsonDecode()`. Also, you should also cache some of the other operations you are doing a lot.

I have made the following example of how I would rewrite the code:

```
List<CoinData> fetchCoinList(ListConfig listConfig) {
  final jsonObject = jsonDecode(listConfig.listData) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  List<CoinData> coinList = [];

  for (int index = listConfig.listStart; index < listConfig.listEnd; index++) {
    final dataMap = jsonObject['data'][index] as Map<String, dynamic>;

    if (dataMap['rank'] == null ||
        dataMap['priceUsd'] == null ||
        dataMap['changePercent24Hr'] == null) continue;

    print(listConfig.listEnd);

    final symbol = dataMap['symbol'] as String;

    coinList.add(CoinData(
        rank: dataMap['rank'] as int,
        name: dataMap['name'] as String,
        symbol: symbol,
        id: dataMap['id'] as String,
        value: double.parse(jsonObject['priceUsd'] as String),
        percentChange: double.parse(jsonObject['changePercent24Hr'] as String),
        image:
            'https://static.coincap.io/assets/icons/${symbol.toLowerCase()}@2x.png'));
  }
  return coinList;
}

class CoinData {
  final int rank;
  final String name;
  final String symbol;
  final String id;
  final double value;
  final double percentChange;
  final String image;

  CoinData({
    required this.rank,
    required this.name,
    required this.symbol,
    required this.id,
    required this.value,
    required this.percentChange,
    required this.image,
  });
}
```

Comment: implementing this solution did improve the performance significantly which made it so I only needed to use one seperate isolate only... Thanks.